# Open a link in an iOS web app that's been added to the Home Screen?

Tags: ios, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

Recent versions of iOS support extra privileges (for example, the [Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification)) for web apps which have been added to the Home Screen in Safari.

However, there seems to be no way to give someone a link which opens *in* that Home Screen web app.

That is:

1. Alice visits example.com and adds it to the Home Screen with the standard Safari UI
2. Bob sends Alice a link to example.com, via email/WhatsApp/whichever
3. Alice taps the link
4. The link opens in a regular Safari tab (or Alice's choice of browser). It does *not* open in the Home Screen version of the app. And therefore, the Notification API does not work in this Safari tab, because even though there's a Home Screen version which *can* use the extra privileges, Alice isn't using that.

How can a link be created that Alice can tap which will open the Home Screen version of the web app?

Failing that, is there any way for an in-a-browser-tab version of the app to detect that a Home Screen version *exists*, and itself provide a link which causes the web page to be re-opened in the Home Screen version of the app?

Answer (score 2):

There's currently no way, but eventually the [Launch Handler API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/launch-handler/) should provide one. WebKit were asked for their opinion on the API in a [standards issue](https://github.com/WebKit/standards-positions/issues/90) and a [WebKit feature request](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=257785) exists. If a user navigates to an already installed app in Safari, a prompt is displayed that invites the user to *Open in web app*. This isn't detectable by the app, though, as far as I can tell.